# String Slicing and empty string result

Tags: python, string, slice

In the following example:

```
s = '1234567'
s[-2:-5] == ''
```

I am confused as to why the substring wouldn't be '654' and is instead the empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to include the `step` parameter in the slice. It is `1` by default; therefore, by default, if `start` is greater than `stop`, the slice will be empty. Specify the `step` as `-1`:

```
s = '1234567'
print(s[-2:-5:-1])
# 654
```

In essence, it will start at index `-2` at go backwards to index `-5` instead of trying to go forward to index `-5`, which is impossible.